# Scroll view with UIWebView and labels

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView with labels above it (see picture), but when I scroll down, the labels just stay in place and the web view scrolls down. How can I make everything scroll down in one motion ?

[image]

```
        self.editorialDetailWebView.loadHTMLString(editorialArticleContentThroughSegue!, baseURL: nil)
    self.editorialDetailWebView.sizeToFit()

    self.editorialDetailScrollView.addSubview(editorialDetailWebView)
    self.editorialDetailScrollView.addSubview(editorialDetailHeadlineLabel)
    self.editorialDetailScrollView.addSubview(editorialDetailAuthorLabel)
    self.editorialDetailScrollView.addSubview(editorialDetailPublishDateLabel)
    self.editorialDetailScrollView.addSubview(editorialDetailVolumeAndIssueLabel)

    let webViewHeight = self.editorialDetailWebView.scrollView.bounds.height
    let webViewWidth = self.editorialDetailWebView.scrollView.bounds.width

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    editorialDetailScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height * 2.0)

}
```

Screenshot of my issue now:

[image: Part 1]

[image: Part 2]

Comment: If all you are doing is appending som labels to the the of the html and you are in control of the html content directly I think you might be better off just modifying the html.

Answer (score 0):

Add your views to the webview's scrollview

```
[self.webview.scrollView addSubview:self.myLabel];
```

Comment: When I do that, the labels disappear from the screen.

Comment: I managed to make everything scroll together, but now it won't load the rest of my web content! How do I properly set the size of the webview's frame so that I can see all of its contents ? When I scroll down, the labels and the web view scroll down, but then the web view is cut off and nothing else appears, I'm just scrolling down on white space. See my edit.